# Using [delphi] MadExcept errorhandling with MS Exchange Server 2007

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, exchange-server, madexcept

I currently use [madExcept](http://madshi.net/madExceptDescription.htm).MailAsSmtpClient to send my bug reports. However a couple of large clients have upgraded to Exchange Server 2007 and we can't get the SMTP support for our app configured (the app runs on individual workstations so the messages aren't all coming from one IP. We can configure an authenticated account in exchange and access it via SMTP from other clients but it rejects madExcept for some reason).

So I have two questions
1) has anyone successfully configured that combo ? or 
2) is there an example somewhere of how to use the madExcept.UploadViaHTTP option?

Comment: How can an honest question get minus two votes and no comments? Cowards.

Comment: If you upload via HTTP a web server is required which accepts POST requests on an URL. The bug report parts will be posted as form parameters, encoded multipart/form-data.

Comment: PHP example code for HTTP upload can be found here: http://forum.madshi.net/viewtopic.php?t=4611

Comment: @mjustin: thanks, that's what I needed - got the viaHTTP up and running. If you made your reply an answer rather than a comment I would mark it as the accepted answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you upload a madExceptbug report via HTTP a web server is required which accepts POST requests. The bug report parts will be posted as form parameters, encoded as multipart/form-data. PHP example code for HTTP upload can be found here: http://forum.madshi.net/viewtopic.php?t=4611